# Error de autenticación al subir mis cambios a GitHub

Tags: git, github

Tengo más de una semana intentando subir los cambios de mi proyecto a **GitHub** pero al escribir el comando `git push` y colocar las credenciales de mi cuenta esta me lanza este mensaje:

`Username for 'https://github.com': Password for 'https://braylin16@github.com': remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead. remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Braylin16/thecanario.git/'` 
Lo más curioso es que cierro la sesión de mi cuenta en el navegador, en el sitio web y al iniciar nuevamente la sesión con las mismas credenciales que coloco en la consola se me abre la sesión sin ningún tipo de problemas y ya he realizado esto un millón de veces becando si es un error en alguna de las teclas de mi **PC** pero nada de eso.

La verdad es que no se que es lo que esta causando este problema. Intente con otra consola llamada **GitBash** y también me lanza el error de autenticación en esa consola.

Alguien que me ayude por favor.

Comment: [Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to) está la respuesta a tu pregunta pero en inglés.

Comment: Las credenciales para iniciar sesión y las credenciales para modificar código en el repo ya no son las mismas y el mensaje te lo está diciendo.

Comment: Deberías usar una llave ssh o gpg para manejar tu proyecto, ademas de que es mas seguro hacerlo con llaves de alto cifrado no tendrás ese error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hace un tiempo **GitHub** mando mensajes de email explicando que usar la autenticación como medio de `git push` ya no era buena idea por lo que aconsejaron a usar **Token** que es mucho más seguro. Lo que sucede amigo mío es que ya no aceptan tu usuario y contraseña como medio de autenticación para subir tus actualizaciones al servidor remoto de **GitHub**

### Paso 1

Lo que tienes que hacer es sencillo. Ve a **GitHub** y luego a **Setting** una vez en allí baja hasta la opción **Developer Setting** y luego **Personal access tokens** si quieres aquí te dejo un [link directo](https://github.com/settings/tokens)

### Paso 2

Una vez allí solo tienes que oprimir el botón de **Generar new token** y completar el formulario. NOTA: te recomiendo habilitar todas las opciones del formulario oprimiendo los checkbox para así tener todos los privilegios
.

### Paso 3

Ahora solo tienes escribir la siguiente palabra en tu buscador de Windows > **Administrador de credenciales**

[image: Administrador de credenciales]

Luego tienes que seleccionar la opción **Credenciales de Windows**:
Y cliquear donde dice `atom-github/https//api.github.com` allí te saldrá un campo donde colocar el tokens que te genero automáticamente en GitHub y darle a guardar.

[image: Credenciales de Windows]

Ya por ultimo solo tienes que cerrar y volver abril tu consola y volver a lanzar el comando `git push` y colocar tu usuario nuevamente pero ahora en **vez de colocar tu contraseña** vas a colocar el toke que te genero siempre que vayas a hacer un git push