# Como puedo hacer un git push sin este error?

Tags: git, github

He tratado de pasar a remoto mi repositorio local y me es imposible hacer un push. He configurado el keygen, he entrado a la configuracion de desarrollador de github para ingresar el token, he conectado la key publica, al usar mac vi un tutorial donde configuraba desde Keychain Acces, no se que hacer, estoy frustrado.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, un saludo.

```
aettouha@cbr1s3 shell00 % git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': abdeleb
Password for 'https://abdeleb@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/abdeleb/42piscine.git/'
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error de autenticación al subir mis cambios a GitHub](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485655/error-de-autenticaci%c3%b3n-al-subir-mis-cambios-a-github)

Comment: Está mal configurada la llave pública si el error sigue siendo el que muestras.

Comment: Que puedo hacer?

Comment: @edw4rd En la respuesta de la otra pregunta está lo que podés hacer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás usando ssh-keygen para generar unas llaves para usar con github, entonces no utilices el url para el repo que usa https, tienes que usar el url de ssh... que debe ser algo así como `git@github.com:abdeleb/42piscine.git` (eso lo puse de memoria así que verifica en el repositorio en github cual debe ser la dirección).

Comment: Pongo> git remote git@github.com:abdeleb/42piscine.git y nada

Comment: ??? Solo eso no va a funcionar. Tendria que ser: `git remote add un-remoto  git@github.com:abdeleb/42piscine.git; git fetch un-remoto`

Comment: O modificar el URL de un repositorio existente: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:abdeleb/42piscine.git` (u otro remoto que tengas configurado en vez de `origin`)... y luego hacer `git fetch origin`