# No puedo acceder desde gitbash a mi cuenta de github

Tags: git, github, git-push, github-actions, git-pull

Todas las veces que hago un git push o un git pull me sale el login para ingresar y al no ingresar me sale otro login para poner correo y luego otro para la contraseña y al final me sale el error.
he cambiado contraseña y igual no quiere ingresar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: No quiere ingresar a mi cuenta]

Comment: Leé de vuelta el mensaje... "Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021". De hecho, ya hay [varias preguntas al respecto](/search?q=August+13%2C+2021+is%3Aquestion) en el sitio. Por último: los mensajes de error y el código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error de autenticación al subir mis cambios a GitHub](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485655/error-de-autenticaci%c3%b3n-al-subir-mis-cambios-a-github)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acceder a tu cuenta de GitHub desde Gitbash, primero debes generar una clave SSH y agregarla a tu cuenta de GitHub. Para hacerlo, sigue los siguientes pasos:

1. Abre Gitbash y ejecuta el siguiente comando para generar una clave SSH:
2. ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "tu-correo@gmail.com"
3. Cuando se te pregunte dónde guardar la clave, acepta la ruta predeterminada presionando Enter.
4. Luego, te pedirá una contraseña para proteger la clave. Ingresa una contraseña segura y vuelve a escribirla para confirmar.
5. Una vez que se genere la clave, abre el archivo id_rsa.pub que se encuentra en la ruta /c/.ssh/. Este archivo contiene tu clave pública.
6. Accede a tu cuenta de GitHub y ve a la página de Configuración. Luego, selecciona la pestaña "SSH y GPG keys" y haz clic en el botón "New SSH key".
7. En el formulario, ingresa un título para tu clave (puedes poner el nombre de tu ordenador) y pega la clave pública que obtuviste en el paso 4 en el campo de "Key". Finalmente, haz clic en "Add SSH key" para guardar los cambios.

Ahora, cada vez que intentes hacer un push o pull desde Gitbash, se te pedirá la contraseña que ingresaste en el paso 3 para autenticarte en tu cuenta de GitHub.

Comment: Gracias men me fué de gran ayuda tu respuesta.